# PHP/PDO: return query rows without foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am confused about this, I run a query such as

```
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM ...") as $row) { 
  ...do something with row()
```

But when I var_dump `$dbh` it is a PDOstatement object.

This leads me to two questions:

- How does foreach somehow resolve the object into separate rows?
- How can I store all rows in an array, like $arr = $dbh->query(...)? This does not work because it is still an object

I can of course run under the foreach, and do $arr[] = $row, but that seems a bit silly..

Comment: No, `$arr[] = $row;` isn't silly. It's normal, ordinal way.    
PDO has a ready-made helper function to do it at once, but you can make the same function yourself as well. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 7):

1. PHP has some interesting interfaces that let you handle objects as arrays. In this case the `PDOStatement` class implements `Traversable` and this allows the use of `foreach` on it. See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php
2. To get all your results in one array take a look at [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). And also in the future consider checking the PHP documentation on php.net if you run into problems. It's packed with examples and useful user comments.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get the entire result set as array. AS far as what PDO does internally it uses an iterator to access some representation of a recordset. This way you use less memory because youre not pulling the entire result set into php, youre using something resembling a `resource` thats internal to the implementation.